# EPPLUS To Clear Contents of A Range Of Cells

Tags: c#, excel, epplus, cells, epplus-4

I want to use EPPLUS to clear a range of cells.  I tried the syntax below, but it gives me an error of

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

What would be the proper way to clear the contents of cells A24:C36 with EPPLUS?

```
ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage();

ExcelWorksheet ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];

ws.Cells["A24:C36"].Clear();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is correct. I think the `.xlsx` file does not have `Worksheets` with `Sheet1` name.

For example, I created this excel file like this:

[image: excel]

I wanted to erase `A24:C36`. I encountered `null reference` error before executing `ws.Cells["A24:C36"].Clear();` like this:

[image: error]

If I use code below instead of it, it works properly (**Sheet2**).

```
ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage();

ExcelWorksheet ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet2"];

ws.Cells["A24:C36"].Clear();
```

Notice that having no value in `A24:C36` does not make an error.

Comment: The OP code is not correct. `.Clear()` removes all contents, formatting, formulas, etc. If you want to clear contents, you will have to loop through each cell and assign the cell's Formula property to its Value